# Unable to view mounted drives in Samba when mounted to /mnt/ instead of /media/

Tags: mount, samba

**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Desktop)**

I'm unable to view my mounted drives in the 'Other Locations' directory in the file explorer. `lsblk` shows that the drives are mounted at the correct locations specified in FSTAB. I can navigate to the drives and access them directly, despite not showing up in the 'other locations' directory. I cannot access this drive on other machines when navigating to the network share. What is wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

**excerpt from `lsblk`:**

```
sda
└─sda1 ext4 Storage 759e847e-1eba-4676-b73c-a9ae111aa6c3 8.2T 4% /mnt/storage
```

[image: lsblk dump]

**Part of `smb.conf`**

```
[NAS]
 comment = NAS
 browseable = yes
 path = /mnt/Storage/
 read only = no
 guest ok = yes
 force user = root
 force group = root
 force directory mode = 0777
 force create mode = 0777
```

[image]

**excerpt from `/etc/fstab`**

```
UUID=759e847e-1eba-4676-b73c-a9ae111aa6c3 /mnt/storage ext4 defaults 0 0
```

[image]

EDIT: The solution below fixed my issues. I needed to add the flag `x-gvfs-show` in my fstab.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd like to add - when I unmount the drives in the Disks utility then remount them, they re-mount in the /media/'user'/'volumename' directory and are once again viewable in the 'Other Locations' directory.  

Why is this?

Comment: I also removed the flag direct_io in the pool as well which resolved issues with the plex docker container boot loop issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure these are three different problems.

[1] You are mounting it at /mnt/storage but your path in smb.conf is /mnt/Storage - with a capital "S". To Linux these are two different locations.

[2] Even if you change the spelling it still won't show up in "Other Locations" because it's not mounted under /media. It's a udisks2 thing.

You can either mount it as /media/storage or "force" it to "show" up by adding `x-gvfs-show` in your fstab declaration:

```
UUID=bunch-of-numbers /mnt/storage ext4 defaults,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

[3] None of that will have any affect on a samba client being able to resolve the "super-server" host name - if the error persists after fixing [1].

Remember Ubuntu 20 disables SMB1 so there is no Netbios and no netbios name resolution. What version of Windows are you using on the client?

If it's Windows 10 access the server by it's mDNS name:

```
\\super-server.local\nas
```

If you really are running Ubuntu 20 server you will need to install avahi:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

If you are running Ubuntu 20 Desktop - as a server - it's already there.

If you are running something prior to Win10 I would suggest accessing the server by ip address - something like:

```
\\192.168.1.101\nas
```

Comment: [1] Thanks, I missed that!

[2] This is the solution that worked for me!  Once I added this flag to the /etc/fstab the drives I needed to show up now worked

[3] I'm unsure what you mean here, since I'm able to connect with my hostname using \\super-server\nas and \\super-server\media now